# Passing a Specific Id to API http URL Android Studio/ Kotlin

Tags: android, api, http, kotlin

I am new to kotlin and android studio, and am trying to make an app using an NHL stats API. I have a request that sends to get all of the teams and some other information:

```
    fun getTeams(
        @Query("page") page: Int
    ): Call<TeamsResponse>
```

This is the model class:

```
data class teams (
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("division") val division: division,
    @SerializedName("venue") val venue: venue
)

data class division (
    @SerializedName("name") val divName: String
)
data class venue (
    @SerializedName("name") val venName: String,
    @SerializedName("city") val venCity: String
)
```

And the Response:

```
data class TeamsResponse (
    @SerializedName("page") val page: Int,
    @SerializedName("teams") val teams: List<teams>,
    @SerializedName("total_pages") val pages: Int
)
```

The code for the view is pretty simple. It displays all of the information inside of the teams model on a cardView, that you can scroll on. I also have code that gets a response for a roster of a specific team:

```
@GET("api/v1/teams/1/roster")
    fun getRoster(

        @Query("page") page: Int
    ): Call<RosterResponse>
```

Which returns the roster into a list of 'person' objects like so:

```
class RosterResponse (
    @SerializedName("page") val page: Int,
    @SerializedName("roster") val roster: List<roster>,
    @SerializedName("total_pages") val pages: Int

)
```

My Question is, how can I click on one of the teams and have the '1' in "api/v1/teams/1/roster" be replaced with the id of the clicked team. All of my experience in working with APIs is in MVC using c#, so I was trying to work through it like I would in that sort of project. 
I am using Retrofit to build the URL:

```
 private val api: API
    init {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        api = retrofit.create(API::class.java)
    }
```

Is there a way that I can pass the ID of the team when it is clicked to this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `@Path` annotation and pass the id value as an argument when you call that method:

```
@GET("api/v1/teams/{id}/roster")
fun getRoster(
    @Path(value = "id", encoded = false) key: Int,
): Call<RosterResponse>
```